# Telerik: Search is not working with Multiselect from middle of a word

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I am using `Telerik Multiselect` for an `ASP.NET MVC` project and everything is working well, but something that I need is missing. It doesn't suggest me when I start write from the middle of a word.

Please consider the following scenario:
I have the following Three words:

- United States
- Germany
- United Kingdom

If I start typing the letter "U" it will suggest me "United States" and "United Kingdom" but if I write "S" it won't suggest me "United States"

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set filter type to `Contains` for `multiselect`. There are total 3 filter types are there i.e `Contains`, `StartsWith`,`Equal`

```
multiselect.options.filter = "contains";
```

[Telerik ASP.Net MVC Multiselect](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/multiselect/api)